# Does the length of a CSS class or ID matter for file size?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a consensus on CSS class/ID naming conventions. I generally have quite long, descriptive CSS class names, but I'm starting to realise that as my stylesheets get very large, all those extra bytes for class names must add up.

For example, I could use:

`.episode-information-container`

Or I could use:

`.ep-info-box`

Does the length here *really* make that much of a difference **in terms of file size**? Should I always opt for the shortest possible class name - without destroying its readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to trying to reduce your CSS file sizes for performance, every space counts. When you’re developing, it’s OK to format your code in the way that you’re comfortable with. However, there is absolutely no reason not to take out excess characters (a process known as minification) when you actually push your project onto the web where the size of your files really counts.

Too many developers simply don’t minify their files before launching their websites, and I think that’s a huge mistake. Although it may not feel like it makes much of a difference, when you have huge CSS files, it can improve your page response times.

Comment: I agree to minify the css, but not the names of id's and classes. This would require you to also minify the php/html with the same class-changes. Of course it would be good to remove all whitespace from your page.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it matters. CSS is a text format; a CSS file is as large as the number of characters it contains.

But the length of your selectors doesn't make a very appreciable difference, unless you have lots and lots of selectors with long class names. If you're concerned about file size, you can minify your stylesheet to strip whitespace and comments, as well as serve it in a compressed format. That will usually yield a much more significant reduction than simply shortening your class names and IDs. Just focus on making your class names brief yet readable.